# Form inside the show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models (and views and controllers) - Classroom and Course.

In the show view of Classroom, I want to have a form that lets me add a Course to the Classroom.

Do I need to create a new action in my ClassroomsController or can I just use the "show" action? How do I associate form with a specific action in my Controller?

I currently get an error that says "The action 'update' could not be found for ClassroomsController" when I try to submit the form

Comment: Show some codes for better understanding.

Comment: Show action just show someting, if you want modify your resources, go edit/update action. please respect framework which you use. And first thing to know is what is the relation between two models. 1-n ? n-n ? etc. Because building form depends that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put your `course` form in the `classroom` show method.

create the course `form` like:

```
form_for Course.new, :url => course_controller_create_path
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually not creating a new Course. I'm just adding an existing Course to the Classroom.

Comment: guessing you need to form_for Classroom.edit, :url => classroom_controller_edit_path and just assign the course to the classroom.

Comment: then just pass the existing @course object instead of a new course object. and change the url accordingly